# Customizing directus interface

Tags: directus

I'm implementing an Arabic site using directus v7. What are my options of customizing the directus interface to be right-to-left?

I also would like to know the options of having a multi-lingual site that can be both arabic and english (right-to-left and left-to-right).

Answer (score 1):

Directus hasn't been designed for right-to-left text..

You have two options as of right now:

- fork the Directus app and keep your own version that's purely right-to-left, or;
- Use the `style.css` file in `public` to override certain classes to fit your use case better.

Comment: Thanks. Are there other customization options? can I provide my own interface to a certain collection?